# Detect self-assignment in overloaded C++ operators

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

Forgive me if this is a duplicate; I searched but the correct vernacular may be outside my scope of comprehension.

My goal for some arbitrary class and overloaded operator

```
x = x op y
```

would recognize it is being self-assigned and rather than generating a temporary variable just op= to x directly ( I don't just want to overload op=). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `x = x op y` isn't self-assignment. You're creating a new value with `x op y` that gets assigned to `x`.

Comment: So you're wanting `x = x + y` to be converted to `x += y` ?

Comment: `x op y` can return a class with a conversion operator to x's type. The assignment operator can handle that class specially to optimize it. There's a term for this form of optimization which I unfortunately can't remember at the moment.

Comment: @ 0x499602D2 That is precisely what I'm hoping to avoid. @ Approaching Yes exactly, but op + must be able to detect it as well (i.e X += Y and X = X + Y should call the same function)

Comment: @interjay: I think the problem arises from detecting the *value*, and not the *type*

Comment: You can't do this. `operator=`, `operator+=`, and `operator+` are all independent. You'll have to overload them all one way or another if you want complete control over how `x = x + y` gets compiled.

Comment: You can write tool using lib clang.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Detecting what value? In my proposed implementation, `x op y` would return a temporary class without performing the actual calculation. The calculation would be performed when assigning (which could be done in-place), or calling the conversion operator (not in-place).

Comment: I appreciate that they are distinct operators. What I want to know is if I can avoid generating the temporary variable in X = X + Y and rather just sum directly to X (e.g by calling op +=), i suppose the question boils down to: Is there a way to access the lvalue to determine it's identity in X = X op Y?

Comment: @interjay: sry, I meant identity. But now I understand how your solution works. Why don't you post an answer (with an example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to have the operation for `A` op `A`  return a temporary object of another class `APlusA`, without performing the operation itself yet. This class has a conversion operator to `A` that performs the actual calculation when needed.

The trick is that in class `A` you implement a version of `operator=` that takes the temporary object of `APlusA`. If it recognizes that it's operating on the same object, it can then perform the operation in-place, without creating a temporary `A` object. Here's an example ([test on ideone](http://ideone.com/ixypdo)):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    struct APlusA {
        APlusA(const A&a_, const A&b_) : a(a_), b(b_) {}
        const A &a;
        const A &b;

        operator A() const { 
            std::cout << "Creating temporary A" << std::endl; 
            return A(a.val + b.val);
        }
    };

    A(int val_) : val(val_) {}
    friend APlusA operator+(const A&a, const A&b) { return APlusA(a,b); }
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &s, const A &a) { return s << a.val;}

    A& operator=(const APlusA &apa) {
        if (this == &apa.a) {
            std::cout << "Performing in-place operation" << std::endl;
            val += apa.b.val;
        }
        else
        {
            *this = static_cast<A>(apa);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    int val;
};
```

Usage example:

```
int main() {
    A a(4), b(5), c(6);
    std::cout << a+b << std::endl; //Temporary created
    a = b+c;                       //Temporary created
    a = a+b;                       //No temporary - inplace operation
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It's also possible to optimize `a = b + c` to avoid creating a temporary, but I haven't done that here. Other possible optimizations are to handle a chain of operations to avoid creating a temporary at each step.

Comment: That is precisely what I was looking for! I should add ++ for the comment about chains! Brilliant.